# Can you use the `useFactory` property in the Angular / NestJS Module Provider and return a Class instead of an instance?

Tags: angular, design-patterns, dependency-injection, nestjs

I am using NestJS to build an API. I have a Gateway service to a 3rd-party API that decouples the HTTP calls from the data processing logic. Since I don't want to make requests to the API during development, I use a factory function that returns a Gateway class depending on the environment—TinkMockGateway or TinkGateway.

In the factory function I return the class instead of instances and it works. This is surprising because my implementation differs from the Angular / NestJS documentation. In both documentations [[1](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#factory-providers-usefactory), [2](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#using-factory-providers)], they say that you must return an instance of the class you want to inject—which makes sense if we follow the Factory Pattern.

But, when I use the factory function below (NestJS), the dependency is injected correctly (the gateway) depending on the environment.

```js
// other module providers...
{
  provide: TinkGateway,
  useFactory: () => environment.mockTinkGateway ? TinkMockGateway : TinkGateway,
}
```

**Is the framework creating the instances for me or what is going on?**

Answer (score 0):

**It is not the same.**

By using the `useFactory` approach to DI you have to return an instance. That's what the factory pattern says, and it seems that's what Angular / NestJS developers expect as well.

If you use useFactory and then return a class—instead of an instance—you get the class in the classes that depend on the gateway. But, what you want is a (potentially shared) instance. After all, that's the purpose of dependency injection. Look at two `console.dir` examples below:

1. Using a class (same code as in your question):

```js
// bank.repository.ts
//
// Adding a console.dir to see what's the output

@Injectable()
export class BankRepository implements IBankRepository {
  constructor(private tinkGateway: TinkGateway) {
    console.dir(tinkGateway);
  }
}

// Output
>>> [Function: TinkGateway]
```

2. Using an instance:

```js
// Adding the following provider in the module
// (substituting your previous provider).

// ...other providers
{
  provide: TinkGateway,
  useFactory: () =>
    environment.mockTinkGateway
      ? new TinkMockGateway()
      : new TinkGateway(),
  inject: [HttpService, ConfigService],
},
// more providers...

// Output
>>> TinkGateway {}
```